# How to I grab the alternate object than the one I am searching with this inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, a users table and a messages table.

```
users:
    id (int)
    username (varchar)

messages:
    id(int)
    send_id(int)
    receive_id(int)
```

I am using this query which gets me all of the messages that a specific user sent:

```
SELECT users.id, users.username  FROM users
INNER JOIN messages
    ON messages.send_id = users.id
    AND users.id = SOMEUSERID
```

How would I go about grabbing the receiving user's id and username instead of the sending users information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    rec.id, rec.username
FROM
    users send
    JOIN messages ON (messages.send_id = send.id)
    JOIN users rec ON (messages.receive_id = rec.id)
WHERE
    send.id = SOMEUSERID
```